# Calling functions from UIViewController in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I'm looking to call a function inside a UIKit UIViewController from a button managed by Swift UI

In my Swift UI View I have:

```
struct CameraView: View {
        var body: some View {
            cameraViewController = CameraViewController()
...
```

which I see creates two instances, one directly created just like calling any class, and the other created by the required `makeUIViewController` method needed for Swift UI to manage UIKit UIViewControllers.

However when I attached a function to a button in my Swift UI say, `cameraViewController.takePhoto()` The instance that is referenced is not the one displayed.

How can I obtain the specific instance that is displayed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are probably multiple solutions to this problem, but one way or another, you'll need to find a way to keep a reference to or communicate with the `UIViewController`.  Because SwiftUI views themselves are pretty transient, you can't just store a reference in the view itself, because it could get recreated at any time.

Tools to use:

- ObservableObject -- this will let you store data in a *class* instead of a struct and will make it easier to store references, connect data, etc
- Coordinator -- in a `UIViewRepresentable`, you can use a Coordinator pattern which will allow you to store references to the `UIViewController` and communicate with it
- Combine Publishers -- these are totally optional, but I've chosen to use them here since they're an easy way to move data around without too much boilerplate code.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vcLink = VCLink()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VCRepresented(vcLink: vcLink)
            Button("Take photo") {
                vcLink.takePhoto()
            }
        }
    }
}

enum LinkAction {
    case takePhoto
}

class VCLink : ObservableObject {
    @Published var action : LinkAction?
    
    func takePhoto() {
        action = .takePhoto
    }
}

class CustomVC : UIViewController {
    func action(_ action : LinkAction) {
        print("\(action)")
    }
}

struct VCRepresented : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var vcLink : VCLink
    
    class Coordinator {
        var vcLink : VCLink? {
            didSet {
                cancelable = vcLink?.$action.sink(receiveValue: { (action) in
                    guard let action = action else {
                        return
                    }
                    self.viewController?.action(action)
                })
            }
        }
        var viewController : CustomVC?
        
        private var cancelable : AnyCancellable?
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomVC {
        return CustomVC()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomVC, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.viewController = uiViewController
        context.coordinator.vcLink = vcLink
    }
}
```

What happens here:

1. `VCLink` is an `ObservableObject` that I'm using as a go-between to communicate between views
2. The `ContentView` has a reference to the `VCLink` -- when the button is pressed, the `Publisher` on `VCLink` communicates that to any subscribers
3. When the `VCRepresented` is created/updated, I store a reference to the ViewController and the `VCLink` in its `Coordinator`
4. The `Coordinator` takes the `Publisher` and in its `sink` method, performs an action on the stored `ViewController`.  In this demo, I'm just printing the action.  In your example, you'd want to trigger the photo itself.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to make a reference from SwiftUI to your view controller if you need to call its functions directly and without unnecessary code:

```swift
class Reference<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var object: T?
}

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    func resume() {
        print("resume")
    }
    
    func pause() {
        print("pause")
    }
}

struct PlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let reference: Reference<PlayerViewController>
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PlayerViewController {
        let controller = PlayerViewController()
        
        // Set controller to the reference
        reference.object = controller

        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: PlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let reference = Reference<PlayerViewController>()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Resume") {
            reference.object?.resume()
        }
        Button("Pause") {
            reference.object?.pause()
        }
        PlayerView(reference: reference)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Adding { reference.object = uiViewController} in updateUIController to have the latest reference of viewcontroller.

Comment: This is essentially the Coordinator pattern.