# WKWebView url scheme switch blocks messages

Tags: javascript, swiftui, wkwebview

I have a simple WKWebView app in SwiftUI. I have no problems sending and receiving messages from the native code to the JS and vice versa, except when the message is triggered by an app switch, I am using

```
WebView().onOpenURL(perform: {url in
                let coord = WebView.Coordinator()
                coord.paymentResponse(url: url)
            })
```

but anything called by onOpenURL can't send messages to the JS inside the WKWebView. The app continues to work fine when messages are initiated through other means after the switch. Ive tried leaving a delay incase the JS isn't loaded, but that doesn't work. Is this a security feature? I don't get any errors the messages simply don't arrive.

Comment: I have checked that the evaluateJavaScript call is on the main thread, which it is. But the completionHandler never fires.

Comment: Does WebView appears as a view when your app launches? I believe you should put the "onOpenURL" in the main view.

Comment: Yes the webView appears, and the onOpenURL fires when the app returns, I put onOpenURL on the ContentView and evaluateJavaScript is called but still doesn't get to the completion handler.

Comment: Your `coord` is going to go out of scope immediately. I assume you're trying to access the coordinator of the UIViewRepresentable? You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65923718/calling-functions-from-uiviewcontroller-in-swiftui) for an example of how to call into a representable or its coordinator.