# Use YPImagePikcer in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm trying to use YPImagePicker in SwiftUI how can I do it??

https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker

how can I call this function in SwiftUI?

[image]

Comment: Please include code, not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, read by screen readers, etc. What you've included isn't enough to tell anything about your structure, including if you're already using `UIViewRepresentable`. If you are, this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65923718/calling-functions-from-uiviewcontroller-in-swiftui

Comment: there is no need to share entire code this function inside view swiftUI only without UIViewRepresentable?? in other way how can I use YPImagepikcer in swiftui I can't with UIViewRepresentable & UIViewContreollerRepresentable

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using UIViewControllerRepresentable like so...

```swift
struct PhotoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {

            
            var config = YPImagePickerConfiguration()
            YPImagePickerConfiguration.shared = config
    
            let picker = YPImagePicker(configuration: config)
            picker.delegate = context.coordinator

            picker.didFinishPicking { items, cancelled in
                if !cancelled {
                    let images: [UIImage] = items.compactMap { item in
                        if case .photo(let photo) = item {
                            return photo.image
                        } else {
                            return nil
                        }
                    }
                    finishedPicking(images)
                }
                dismiss()
            }        

            return picker
        }
    
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {

        }
    
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }
    
        class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
            let parent: PhotoPicker
    
            init(_ parent: PhotoPicker) {
                self.parent = parent
            }
        }
    }
```

and then call it like this...

```swift
Text("SomeView")
    .sheet(isPresented: $showPhotoPicker) {
        PhotoPicker()
    }
```

Comment: How and where would you call the didFinishPicking?

Comment: `didFinishPicking` is a function of the `YPImagePicker` class, the YP picker will call it on your behalf at the appropriate time, with a completion that you define. I added an update to the answer to demonstrate how you might handle this.