# Pass value from UIViewRepresentable to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, publish-subscribe, combine

I am new to SwiftUI and RealityKit.

I have a data in UIView which was updated by ARView's subscribe to a sceneEvent. When the subscribe function finished, I don't know how to receive the data variable in the ExtendARView in content_view

```
class ExtendARView: ARView {
    private var data: Bool
    
...
}
```

I use a subscribe function in it to alter the data variable

in content_view() I use a UIViewRepresentable:

```
struct ARViewConatiner: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var data: Bool
    
    let arView = TestARView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ExtendARView {
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ExtendARView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

I think I can achieve this by combine framework, or other possible ways?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This type of infrastructure might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65923718/calling-functions-from-uiviewcontroller-in-swiftui

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806

Comment: You have to init the UIView in makeUIView